# Master method is applicable only for divide and conquer algorithm

Tags: algorithm, analysis

Master method is applicable only for divide and conquer algorithm of equal size? Not for all recursive algorithms?

Comment: I believe, given the tags algorithm and analysis, the question refers to the Master Theorem used in analyzing recursive algorithms, a theorem made popular by the popular algorithms textbook Introduction to Algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that Master Theorem does not apply to all recursive problems. In its various proofs, you may see that Master Theorem proceeds by computing the cost of subproblems of equal size with each of them having the identical cost.

So, unless you can divide a given problem into such identically-sized subproblems, Master Theorem would be insufficient in helping you find the solution to it. For instance, a recurrence relation with T(n) depending on T(n-k), for instance, k being any particular integer could not really be solved using Master Theorem. The approach used in its proof, however, would still be useful. (i.e. expanding subproblems until the relation depends solely on the base cases)